# Speaker diarization for 3+ speakers using Azure

Tags: azure, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, speech

Does Azure's batch transcription support speaker diarization for more than 2 speakers?

I checked their [Rest API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/batch-transcription) documentation and didn't find anything relevant.

Are there other ways to do this using Azure cognitive services?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that diarization is limited to two parties. From the MS documentation on V2T batch transcription:

> diarizationEnabled - Optional, false by default. Specifies that
> diarization analysis should be carried out on the input, which is
> expected to be a mono channel **that contains two voices**. Requires
> wordLevelTimestampsEnabled to be set to true.
> [emphasis added]

Source:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/batch-transcription

Cog services now supports [Speaker Recognition](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speaker-recognition-overview), which verifies the voice print of known account holders, and may work fine for n>2 way-conversations, but that only works for known account holders with profiles.

Answer (score 0):

### With API v3.1

To update [Frank's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1702310/1820710), more than 2 speakers seems to be available without speaker recognition now with version 3.1 through the `diarization` property:

> diarization - [..] You need to use this property when you expect three or more
> speakers. For two speakers setting diarizationEnabled property to true is
> enough. [..] The maximum number of speakers for diarization must be less
> than 36 and more or equal to the minSpeakers property.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/speech-service/batch-transcription-create?pivots=rest-api#request-configuration-options

As noted above, the older method of `diarizationEnabled` is still available for
max. 2 speakers.